# Times in G1GC logs

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

I've read a few descriptions of different times printed in G1GC logs but couldn't really prove/understand when I produced them locally. For example, following log was produced on my PC with Java 11. I wanted to know, what's the difference between 0.500ms in the first line vs 0.01s in the second? Was the application paused (because of STW) for 0.500ms or for 10ms (0.01s)? I tried tools like GCeasy, it shows max pause time of 10ms, and in cases where Real = 0.00, GCeasy shows min pause of 0ms. I wonder, what kind of pause is 0.500ms representing then?

> [9.090s][info][gc           ] GC(25) Pause Young (Normal) (G1
> Evacuation Pause) 77M->2M(128M) 0.500ms
>
> [9.090s][info][gc,cpu       ]
> GC(25) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s

Edit: GC Pause time difference in gc.logs vs in JMC

0.687ms pause in gc.log [image]

Where as 1.331 second according to JMC [image]

Comment: @eugene Are you sure, 10ms is the total time. Because, my logs show many cases where pause time is there (non zero) but Real remains 0?

Comment: I will delete the comment since I rushed it in and it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I should post this as an answer, because this is *my* understanding of this log, but it would be too big for a comment it seems.

The total time of the `STW` event was `0.500ms` if you look with the eyes of `G1GC` and was neither `0.500ms` nor `10ms` if you take `Shenandoah` for example. When you use `G1GC`, `STW event` is treated as `0.500ms`, using `Shenandoah`, will result in `0.500ms + delta`; where this `delta` will be the cumulative time it took to bring all `java threads` to a `safepoint` (also called `TTSP` - time to safe point) + whatever clean-up was needed for that `safepoint`.  May be a picture will make this easier:

```
   |------|------------------------|---------| 
   | TTPS |   G1 Evacuation Pause  | CleanUp |
   |------|------------------------|---------|
```

`G1GC` treats as the `STW Event` the `G1 Evacuation Pause` region *only*. `Shenandoah` for example, treats the entire thing as the `STW` event (all 3 regions). Who is right? I will leave this up to you to decide.

You can enable the safepoint granularity for `G1GC` via `-Xlog:safepoint*`, for example.

The tools that you are using have their own "opinion" oh how to treat each time produced by the logs, I guess; but it is absolutely not `10 ms`. Why? As you have seen already (as you say in comments) there are times when you will get something like this in logs:

```
[9.090s][info][gc ] GC(25) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 77M->2M(128M) 0.500ms

[9.090s][info][gc,cpu ] GC(25) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=**0.00s**
```

Notice the `Real=0.00s`. Does this mean there was *no pause*? Of course not, it just means there was no cpu time spent.

Comment: if you see my Edit, different pause times are shown on gc.log vs JMC. How come, simply showing pause time for a collection is that different on different tools?

Comment: @Abidi I can't tell what number is in JMC, I would have to read the documentation. But anyway, this sounds like a different question you need to ask.

Comment: @Abidi well, I only had time now to read the JMC documentation and that value is: _the accumulated duration of the collector running time. The time is the sum of the wall-clock time of all GC events_. Did you happen to read and understand that?

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I didn't quite understand your answer, sorry about my poor understanding. But finally I was able to figure it out and I "think" it's same as you said. The total GC time is 0.500ms. What I dont' understand is, if and how it's linked with User, Sys and Real times. I'm ignoring this for now.

Comment: @Abidi there's nothing to be sorry for, I am learning these things too.